# Drawing multiple sets of multiple lines on a d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 chart that displays two lines showing a country's imports and exports over time. It works fine, and uses the modular style described in ['Developing a D3.js Edge'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DNJ1UMM) so that I could quite easily draw multiple charts on the same page.

However, I now want to pass in data for *two* countries and draw imports and exports lines for both of them. After a day of experimentation, and getting closer to making it work, I can't figure out how to do this with what I have. I've successfully drawn multi-line charts with d3 before, but can't see how to get there from here.

You can view what I have here: http://bl.ocks.org/philgyford/af4933f298301df47854 (or the [gist](https://gist.github.com/philgyford/af4933f298301df47854))

I realise there's a lot of code. I've marked with "Hello" the point in script.js where the lines are drawn. I can't work out how to draw those lines once for each country, as opposed to just for the first one, which is what it's doing now.

I'm *guessing* that where I'm applying `data()` isn't correct for this usage, but I'm stumped.

**UPDATE:** I've put a simpler version on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/RCgaL/

Comment: It would help if you could narrow it down to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I couldn't see how to do that easily, but you're right - I will have a go.

Comment: I've put a simpler version on jsfiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/RCgaL/

Comment: Your current code seems to be set up to create several charts (which I have done with nested selections [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RCgaL/1/)). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I want the option to create several charts -- it seems like a useful ability -- but in this case I only want one chart with both sets of import/export data plotted on it.

Comment: Ok, so something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RCgaL/2/)? This would actually be the first practical example of selections nested 3 deep I've seen :)

Comment: Yes! It'll take me a while to work out exactly what's happening, but that is it, thank you! (If you post as an answer I'll accept it.) Does the way I'm doing this seem daft, as this all seems overly complex for a line chart to me...?

Comment: The main reason why it's so complex is because you're using a chart component and it's all data driven. I'll add an answer with some more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to achieving what you want are [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). You first bind the entire data to the SVG element, then add a group for each group in the data (each country), and finally get the values for each line from the data bound to the group. In code, it looks like this (I've simplified the real code here):

```
var svg = d3.select(this)
              .selectAll('svg')
              .data([data]);

  var g = svg.enter().append('svg').append('g');

  var inner = g.selectAll("g.lines").data(function(d) { return d; });
  inner.enter().append("g").attr("class", "lines");

  inner.selectAll("path.line.imports").data(function(d) { return [d.values]; })
      .enter().append("path").attr('class', 'line imports')
      .attr("d", function(d) { return imports_line(d); });
```

The structure generated by this looks like `svg > g > g.lines > path.line.imports`. I've omitted the code for the export line here -- that would be below `g.lines` as well. Your data consists of a list of key-value pairs with a list as value. This is mirrored by the SVG structure -- each `g.lines` corresponds to a key-value pair and each path to the value list.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RCgaL/2/).

Comment: Thanks so much Lars. I'm struggling to fully comprehend this, but I keep on trying with d3 and hope I'm inching forward one step at a time. Your help is invaluable.

Comment: Having got this working, one point I've spent a long time struggling with is how to get this chart to update with new data. Having drawn the chart, if I pass in a new `data` array how do I transition to the new data? I've tried many variations based on simpler working examples, but so far... no change.

Comment: It may be better if you ask a separate question about this with a more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: I've now done that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611972/making-a-d3-chart-update-with-new-data

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you're thinking to imperative. That's why you have so much code. I really can't put it better than Mike Bostock, you have to start [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/):

```
svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d.x)
    .attr("cy", d.y)
    .attr("r", 2.5);
```

> But that’s just a single circle, and you want many circles: one for each data point. Before you bust out a for loop and brute-force it, consider this mystifying sequence from one of D3’s examples.
>
> Here data is an array of JSON objects with x and y properties, such as: [{"x": 1.0, "y": 1.1}, {"x": 2.0, "y": 2.5}, …].

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 2.5);
```

I'll leave translating this example to the "from one line to many lines" as an excerxise.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm sure I am thinking the wrong way, which is why I've struggled with d3 for so many cumulative weeks/months! I understand the example, but the model I've adapted seems to use the enter/update/exit idea for creating multiple charts, rather than lines. And I can't figure out how to use it for both. I'll keep poking it.