# Making a d3 chart update with new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have [an example of a chart on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/UR2Cg/1/) which has multiple groups of multiple lines. It draws successfully, but I would like to be able to transition to new sets of data.

The example should update with new data after 4 seconds. Although the chart gets called (and outputs something in the console), the lines aren't updated.

I've tried lots of variations based on existing, simpler examples, with no luck. I suspect its the nested data [based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388549/drawing-multiple-sets-of-multiple-lines-on-a-d3-js-chart) that's confusing me even more than usual.

SO insists I have some code in the answer, so here's where I assume I need to add/change something:

```
  svg.transition().attr({ width: width, height: height });
  g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left +','+ margin.right + ')');

  var lines = g.selectAll("g.lines").data(function(d) { return d; });
  lines.enter().append("g").attr("class", "lines");

  lines.selectAll("path.line.imports")
      .data(function(d) { return [d.values]; })
      .enter().append("path").attr('class', 'line imports');

  lines.selectAll('path.line.imports')
      .data(function(d) { return [d.values]; })
      .transition()
      .attr("d", function(d) { return imports_line(d); });

  // repeated for path.line.exports with exports_line(d).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you're determining the top-level `g` element that everything is appended to:

```
var g = svg.enter().append('svg').append('g');
```

This will only be set if there is no SVG already, as you're only handling the enter selection. If it exists, `g` will be empty and therefore nothing will happen. To fix, select the `g` explicitly afterwards:

```
var g = svg.enter().append('svg').append('g').attr("class", "main");
g = svg.select("g.main");
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UR2Cg/2/).

Comment: Oh good lord, such a small change and it works! Thank you Lars. I've spent hours and hours (even days) trying to work this out and was nowhere near. I'm starting to wonder if my brain just isn't wired correctly for d3.js :(